# How to declare webelement type variable in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-java

I am using Intellj java maven project with selenium webdriver, it shows error when I try to declare a variable of the type `WebElement` as follows:

```
WebElement email =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")).isDisplayed();
```

Snapshot of the code:

[image: code screenshot here]

Is should allow me to declare the variable to store the webelement

Comment: Because `element.isDisplayed()` returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: please, don't use screenshots for showing your code

Answer (score 0):

As per the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGpsj.png) you provided your line of code is:

```
WebElement email =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")).isDisplayed();
```

Though [**`findElement()`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) returns the matched [**WebElement**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) but you have invoked the [**`isDisplayed()`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) method on the WebElement, which returns a **`boolean`**.

You can't assign the *boolean* value to a variable of type WebElement. hence you see the unlined error.

---

### Solution

You have to follow either of the two (2) approaches:

- Return the WebElement:

  ```
  WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]"))
  ```
- Return the boolean result of *`isDisplayed()`*:

  ```
  Boolean bool = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")).isDisplayed();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is faced by every qa person in test automation services company while creating a framework initially.

The above provided line of code **WebElement email =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="email"]")).isDisplayed();**  will throw an compilation error "WebElement cannot be resolved to a type" due to type mismatch.The reason behind is:

email type is WebElement and 'isDisplayed()' method return type is Boolean. You are assigning Boolean value type to WebElement type which is incorrect.

The correct way to use them in your framework are given below:

1. WebElement email =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="email"]"));

   Boolean emailDisplayed = email.isDisplayed();
2. Boolean emailDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="email"]")).isDisplayed();